# Can i create database in the browser ? except localstorage/indexedDB/session storage

Tags: database, sqlite

I've developed a website for a client. It is a sort of ERP system and has a large database. But my client wants to run this website without the internet as he has seen some other website that runs without internet. So my question is that, Can I create a database in the browser? if not then please suggest me how should I go about this? are there any extensions available?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use sqlite or [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) running on the Server/PC that is also hosting the Website ... but that is not exactly a Coding-related question, you might find better answers on another StackExchange Site for example that for [Database-Admins](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) or for [WebApplications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) / [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Edit: instead of sqlite I ment [MySql](https://www.mysql.com) -- I used both MySql and MongoDB, so I know it works. I am prefering MongoDB for its simplicity tho.